# Identities that connect antipode with multiplication and comultiplication

Tags: hopf-algebras

The group algebra $k(G)$ of any group $G$ satisfies as a Hopf algebra the following identities:
$$
S\otimes S\circ \varDelta=\sigma\circ\Delta\circ S
$$
$$
\nabla\circ S\otimes S=S\circ\nabla\circ\sigma
$$
where $S$ is the antipode, $\Delta$, the comultiplication, $\nabla$, the multiplication, and $\sigma:x\otimes y\mapsto y\otimes x$.

Is this valid for all Hopf algebras or only for some special class?

EDIT. I asked this question later at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178319/identities-that-connect-antipode-with-multiplication-and-comultiplication).

Answer (score 2):

Your first identity says that $S$ is a coalgebra anti-homomorphism, and your second says $S$ is an algebra anti-homomorphism.  Both of these are true for all Hopf algebras, see for example http://library.msri.org/books/Book43/files/nik.pdf or http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hopf+algebra, or one of the books by Sweedler or Abe.

Comment: Do these Hopf algebras lie in the category of vector spaces, or in an arbitrary braided monoidal category?

Comment: These are Hopf algebra objects in the category of vector spaces, I don't know a reference for more general categories, possibly the ncatlab has something.

Comment: My category is not the category of vector spaces. :(

Comment: Try expressing the proof diagrammatically, you probably find it works anywhere.